# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Result has already been consumed

Tags: android

I'm currently studying ways to sync data between an Android device to Google Drive and stumbled upon the sample code at https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickeditor , but I'm encountering an issue when opening an existing file and then tapping on 'Save Changes'. Basically the problematic code is here:

```
@Override
protected com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status doInBackground(DriveId... params) {
    R await;

    DriveFile file = params[0].asDriveFile();
    PendingResult<DriveContentsResult> openDriveContentsResult = file.open(mClient, DriveFile.MODE_WRITE_ONLY, null);

    if (!openDriveContentsResult.await().getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        return openDriveContentsResult.await().getStatus();
    }

    Changes changes = edit(openDriveContentsResult.await().getDriveContents());
    PendingResult<MetadataResult> metadataResult = null;
    PendingResult<com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status> closeContentsResult = null;

    if (changes.getMetadataChangeSet() != null) {
        metadataResult = file.updateMetadata(mClient, changes.getMetadataChangeSet());
        if (!metadataResult.await().getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            return metadataResult.await().getStatus();
        }
    }

    if (changes.getDriveContents() != null) {
        closeContentsResult = changes.getDriveContents().commit(mClient, null);
        closeContentsResult.await();
    }
    return closeContentsResult.await().getStatus();
}
```

The exact line throwing the error is:

```
Changes changes = edit(openDriveContentsResult.await().getDriveContents());
```

The Error is `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Result has already been consumed`. I referred to the PendingResult class reference and it clearly states that "After the result has been retrieved using `await()` or delivered to the result callback, it is an error to attempt to retrieve the result again." Fair enough I guess.

The problem is, how am I supposed to fix this properly? I have commented out

```
if (!metadataResult.await().getStatus().isSuccess()) {...}
```

for now to avoid calling `await()` twice (for sake of debugging), BUT (as expected) then results into the same error at

```
return closeContentsResult.await().getStatus();
```

So...how can I fix this? Pretty please?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. For anyone that's getting frustrated over this:

```
@Override
protected com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status doInBackground(DriveId... params)
{
    R await;
    DriveFile file;
    Changes changes;
    PendingResult<DriveContentsResult> openDriveContentsResult;
    DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult;
    PendingResult<MetadataResult> updateMetadataResult;
    MetadataResult metaDataResult;
    PendingResult<com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status> commitResults;
    com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status closeContentResults = null;

    file                    = params[0].asDriveFile();
    openDriveContentsResult = file.open(mClient, DriveFile.MODE_WRITE_ONLY, null);

    driveContentsResult     = openDriveContentsResult.await();
    if (!driveContentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess())
    {
        return driveContentsResult.getStatus();
    }

    changes                 = edit(driveContentsResult.getDriveContents());
    updateMetadataResult    = null;
    commitResults           = null;

    if (changes.getMetadataChangeSet() != null)
    {
        updateMetadataResult = file.updateMetadata(mClient, changes.getMetadataChangeSet());
        metaDataResult       = updateMetadataResult.await();

        if (!metaDataResult.getStatus().isSuccess())
        {
            return metaDataResult.getStatus();
        }
    }

    if (changes.getDriveContents() != null)
    {
        commitResults = changes.getDriveContents().commit(mClient, null);
        closeContentResults = commitResults.await();
    }

    if (null == commitResults)
    {
        return commitResults.await().getStatus();
    }
    else
    {
        return closeContentResults.getStatus();
    }
}
```